# Grails i18 message properties

Tags: grails, grails-constraints

I want to change the default message for `typemismatch.java.math.BigDecimal` in i18 message properties file for different properties.

In the documentation it says, use `typeMismatch.$className.$propertyName` to customize but that does not work for me.

Did anyone come across this issue. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the exact property you added ?

Answer (score 2):

For a property `foo`, the following should override the default message:

```
typeMismatch.java.math.BigDecimal.foo=Property {0} must be a valid number
```

Comment: typeMismatch.java.math.BigDecimal.amount = Amount value is invalid. does not work for me. Do i need to specify the class name the property belongs to.

Answer (score 0):

For a property `foo`:

`typeMismatch.foo=Custom message`

Or more specific, for a property foo in a form:

`typeMismatch.formName.foo=Custom message`

Answer (score 0):

To override the default message, you need fully qualified class name at `$className` of documentation `typeMismatch.$className.$propertyName`.

Eg. `typeMismatch.com.xxx.hrms.Employee.salary=Please Enter valid number`